# Dont understand why I'm getting a compile error

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting a compile error: Else without If and I'm not sure why.

```
Dim product As String

    Do Until product = "P" Or product = "p"
    product = Left(InputBox("Please enter product number", "Product please", "Enter product number here"), 1)
        If product = "P" Or product = "p" Then MsgBox "Thank you"
        ElseIf product = "Enter product number here" Then Exit Sub
        Else: MsgBox "Please enter a valid product number"
        End If
    Loop
```

Comment: Unrelated, but how could your `product` variable be `"Enter product number here"` since you take the `Left(,1)` of whatever is entered? It could only be a single character.

Comment: Just a quick tip: use "If LCase(product) = "p"". Better than using all those "Or" statements.

Comment: The colon after `Else` is an error.

Answer (score 2):

Because your If statement is a bit more complicated then just "Do one thing if this condition is true" you should separate the conditions from the actions into their own lines:

```
Dim product As String

Do Until product = "P" Or product = "p"
    product = Left(InputBox("Please enter product number", "Product please", "Enter product number here"), 1)

    If product = "P" Or product = "p" Then 
         MsgBox "Thank you"
    ElseIf product = "Enter product number here" Then 
         Exit Sub
    Else
         MsgBox "Please enter a valid product number"
    End If
Loop
```

Also as I noted in my comment your `ElseIF` condition will never hit and you will be stuck in endless loop if you run this code.

Comment: Ah that does it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Think about the logic flow - what happens after the first `IF` when the `MsgBox` is put on the same line.  Use F8 to Step Into the code below to figure it out.  Cheers!

```
Sub test()

    Dim product As String

    Do Until product = "P" Or product = "p"
        product = Left(InputBox("Please enter product number", "Product please", "Enter product number here"), 1)
        If product = "P" Or product = "p" Then
            MsgBox "Thank you"
            ElseIf product = "Enter product number here" Then Exit Sub
            Else: MsgBox "Please enter a valid product number"
        End If
    Loop

End Sub
```